# change background color once after few seconds

Tags: css, background-color, css-animations

Is it possible to change the background color of `<p>` element after few seconds ( 10 to 20 seconds ) using css [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jH8Ke/)? I don't want to use js.

```
<p style="background:#E1FEE0;">Human</p>
```

Comment: See [this example](http://designshack.net/articles/css/fun-with-pulsing-background-colors-in-css3/) using animations and keyframes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using a CSS animation, you could just jump from `99.9%` to `100%`. Just set the initial background color (`#E1FEE0`) within `99.9%`, then the final background color within `100%`. If you want the color to transition, just increase the gap and use something like `80%` for [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3sRV8/).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/326mJ/)

```
p {
    display: inline;
    animation: background-fade 10s forwards;
}

@keyframes background-fade {
    99.9% {
        background:#E1FEE0;
    }
    100% {
        background:#000;
    }
}
```

Other vendor prefixes omitted for simplicity and brevity.

Comment: @Beginner Only the animation properties.. not the keyframes. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jw9c6/).

Comment: @Beginner: No. If you must, you can put it inside a `<style></style>`.

Answer (score 3):

Actually You can.
You should use CSS animation to achieve this.
[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/7zpdY/) example of CSS declaration:

```
@-webkit-keyframes change-color {
  0%   { background-color: red; }
  100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes change-color {
  0%   { background-color: red; }
  100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes change-color {
  0%   { background-color: red; }
  100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes change-color {
  0%   { background-color: red; }
  100% { background-color: green; }
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation: change-color 2s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    change-color 2s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      change-color 2s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         change-color 2s infinite; /* IE 10+ */
}
```

Try this on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zpdY/).

For more reading, [here's](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) the link about CSS animations.